# How to pass a parameter from template client to master template and then use it in a composite attribute?

Tags: jsf, parameters, facelets

I have a composite component (a navigation bar) that takes a variable called 'activeIndex' to determine which tab is active (obviously). The nav bar is a composite component with an attribute as follows:

```
<!-- INTERFACE -->
<cc:interface>
    <cc:attribute name="tab"/>
</cc:interface>

<!-- IMPLEMENTATION -->
<cc:implementation>

    <pou:tabMenu activeIndex="#{cc.attrs.tab}" 
                 styleClass="margin-top-52">  

        <pou:menuitem value="Home" url="#" />  
        <pou:menuitem value="About" url="#"/> 
        <pou:menuitem value="iConsult" url="#"/> 
        <pou:menuitem value="Contact" url="#"/>  

    </pou:tabMenu> 

</cc:implementation>
```

So from here I can pass in the active tab using:

```
<!-- Composite Navigation -->
<ez:anonymous-navigation tab="2"/>
```

The problem is that the above code is placed in a template.xhtml and I don't want to specify the tab value `2` in the template. Instead I need to pass this value back from the page that implements the template that in turn passes that to the above code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`<ui:param>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/ui/param.html). Here's a kickoff example:

`client.xhtml`:

```
<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/template.xhtml"
    xmlns="..."
>
    <ui:param name="tab" value="2" />
    ...
</ui:composition>
```

`/WEB-INF/template.xhtml`:

```
<ez:anonymous-navigation tab="#{tab}"/>
```

Comment: As always... spot on! Thanks BalusC

Comment: Can we set a default value for that variable inside template.xhtml in case client doesn't define it ?

Comment: @BalusC nice answer. Is there any way to declare in the template that `tab` will be defined by the client? (like a list of attributes in `composite:interface`)